# jboss with s3ping in ec2

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jgroups

Am trying to get s3ping discovery method working in jboss as 7. I have deployed a sample web app which is clustered. As of now i have a single node. But in the near future i ill be adding more nodes in the cluster..

I have modified the file standalone-ha.xml with the required s3 credentials and bucket details.

```
 <stack name="s3ping">
                <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp" diagnostics-socket-binding="jgroups-diagnostics"/>
                <protocol type="S3_PING">
                    <property name="access_key">
                        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    </property>
                    <property name="secret_access_key">
                        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    </property>
                    <property name="prefix">
                        MyjbossBucket
                    </property>
                    <property name="timeout">
                        6000
                    </property>
                </protocol>
                <protocol type="MERGE2"/>
                <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
                <protocol type="FD"/>
                <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                <protocol type="BARRIER"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK"/>
                <protocol type="UNICAST2"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                <protocol type="UFC"/>
                <protocol type="MFC"/>
                <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
            </stack>
```

And i start this jboss instance by using the below command.

```
./standalone.sh -b 10.1.137.250 -bmanagement=10.1.137.250 -c standalone-ha.xml -Djboss.default.jgroups.stack=s3ping -Djgroups.bind.address=10.1.137.250 -Djboss.node.name=node1
```

Its getting started successfully, but am unable to see any node information file created inside the s3 bucket. Kindly please guide me through the correct method to get this done...Or am i doing some mistake in the configs...

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Have you changed the default-stack?

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:1.1" default-stack="s3ping">
```